# Knockout.js dynamically selecting template error: "Cannot find template with ID''"

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, knockout.js

My target is to show "noSets" template if observableArray length less 0 and render template with item details - "showSets", if observableArray length greater 0. I'd like to use  templates for this purpose, but FireBug show error: Cannot find template with ID "templatename". 
Here is ViewModel:

```
function SetsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.usersets = ko.observableArray();
            self.getTemplate = function () {
                return self.usersets().length > 0 ? "showSets" : "noSets";
            }
  }
$(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new SetsViewModel(), document.getElementById('user_sets'));
});
```

And here is HTML markup:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: $root.getTemplate, foreach: usersets }" id="user_sets">
            <script type="text/html" id="noSets">
                <p>You do not have items yet.</p>
            </script>
            <script type="text/html" id="showSets">
                <div class="block">
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $data.SetId" />
                    <div class="fav" data-bind="css: { fullop: $data.IsFavorite == true }">
                        <img alt="" src="img/fav.png" data-bind="click: $root.setFavorite">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: $data.SetImg }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="txt">
                        <h3 data-bind="text: $data.SetName, click: $root.go"></h3>
                        <p><span data-bind="text: $data.ItemsNumber + ' вещей,'"></span><span data-bind="    text: ' общая цена ' + $data.SetPrice + ' руб'"></span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the templates outside of the `div` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the templates outside the `div` that you're binding to as a work around. As @JeffMercado states:

> The actual problem was that since the user_sets uses a template binding, the body is discarded (and the templates along with it)

```js
function SetsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.usersets = ko.observableArray([{SetId: 1, SetName: 'Name 1'}]);
            self.getTemplate = function () {
                return self.usersets().length > 0 ? "showSets" : "noSets";
            }
  }
$(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new SetsViewModel(), document.getElementById('user_sets'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="noSets">
    <p>You do not have items yet.</p>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="showSets">
    <div class="block">
        <input data-bind="value: $data.SetId" />
        <div class="txt">
            <h3 data-bind="text: 'Set name:' + $data.SetName"></h3>                        
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate, foreach: usersets }" id="user_sets">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, I didn't knew it.

Comment: The templates doesn't necessarily have to appear before the bindings that uses them, the bindings aren't applied until the document is ready so they'll exist by then. The _actual_ problem was that since the `user_sets` uses a template binding, the body is discarded (and the templates along with it).

Answer (score 1):

I think named templates are potentially the wrong approach to this specific issue - they're more designed for when you want a different template for each item, which isn't the case here.  Instead, it would be more appropriate to show an entirely different `div` when there are 0 items:

```
<div data-bind="visible: usersets().length == 0">
    You have no sets
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: usersets().length > 0, foreach: usersets" id="user_sets">
    <div class="block">
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $data.SetId" />
        <div class="fav" data-bind="css: { fullop: $data.IsFavorite == true }">
            <img alt="" src="img/fav.png" data-bind="click: $root.setFavorite">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: $data.SetImg }">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
            <h3 data-bind="text: $data.SetName, click: $root.go"></h3>
            <p><span data-bind="text: $data.ItemsNumber + ' вещей,'"></span><span data-bind="    text: ' общая цена ' + $data.SetPrice + ' руб'"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did tried this approach as well but no success, probably I did something wrong before.